# Disable Civ 5 screen jumping to battles, without disabling all animations

Tags: civilization-5

Basically like the title, I want to make it where my screen doesn't jump to all the little AI or other player battles, but by choosing quick battles that completely disables all animations. Is there a best of both worlds where I can still see the fighting that's on my screen but not have to get pulled away from what I'm doing to watch other battles that don't effect me.

It only happens when  your teamed up with another country.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable battle cycling of other civs in Civilization 5?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102712/how-can-i-disable-battle-cycling-of-other-civs-in-civilization-5)

Comment: I think what this user is asking for is a bit different, although I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: The upvoted and accepted answer of that question clearly does not answer this one. Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have logged over 300+ hours of Civ V and there is simply no way to do both. You can only disable battle animations, but not the "get dragged around" part

Comment: It's to bad, I kind of ruins it for me, would rather see a pop saying "battle over here" or something lol.